# How to flex images, iframes and video elements and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, flexbox

I have 5 media items (mix of images, videos en youtube video in iframe) which needs to be aligned using flexbox. When I remove the video and iframe everything works just fine. Somehow, when I add video/iframe, everything gets stretched, video's have a greather width, the video element gets a hugh height. How can I create a row of 5 items, with all equal height and width?

Answer (score 0):

This makes the container where the videos or images are inside to be equal widths. Your videos/images inside the the child divs need to scale to fit the parent width to 100% in width.
html:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" #video1>
     <!--place your image or video here, and make it use the whole width of the 'child' div-->
   </div>
   <div class="child" #image1>
      <!--place your image or video here, and make it use the whole width of the 'child' div-->
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   width:100%; // or something similar;
}

.child {
  width: 20%; // 20*5=100% of parent;
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to display 5 videos/images on small devices you can set a `min-width` on the child and use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" #image1>
      <!--place your image or video here, and make it use the whole width of the 'child' div-->
   </div>
   <div class="child" #video1>
      <!--place your image or video here, and make it use the whole width of the 'child' div-->
   </div>
</div>
```

and then the css:

```
.parent {
   display:flex;
   width:100vw;
   flew-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
   width:20%;
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this maintain aspect ratio for both iframe as video? Because the aspect ratio of video is 4:3 and the aspect ratio for the iframe is 16:9 but they have to have equal width and height. Object-cover (or something similar) should make sure that the videos are scaled within its view.